# moment js:month format number not starting with zero

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am trying to format a UTC time stamp to date string  and I want month index to start with 0

eg:

0 - January,

1 - February

and so on.

```
moment(1516102320000).format('YYYY-M-DD-h-mm-s');
```

**Output:** `2018-1-16-5-02-0`

**Expected output:** `2018-0-16-5-02-0`

As per their docs month index start with zero but it doesn't work for me.

Moment version: ^2.20.1

Comment: I think it only works when you provide details using array. Please visit: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/array/

Comment: how? like this way `moment([1516102320000])`

Comment: Hey look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48294127/9211830 I tried it and it's working.

Comment: Why would you want a formatted date string to start counting months at 0?

Answer (score 3):

The `format` method will display months from 1 through 12. See [this](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) link for more info about format. The input is 0 indexed. If you specifically need 0 indexed months, you can use `moment.month`

Comment: how to use i tried `moment().month(0).format()` but still the same

Comment: Have a look at this github issue https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2365. Might help

Answer (score 2):

Try this `moment(1516102320000).year() +"-"+ moment(1516102320000).month()+"-"+moment(1516102320000).day()`

This is the way you can achieve your desired output. `month()` will return you 0 for January. `format()` will return 1 for January so in order to achieve this output `2018-0-2` you have to use this code `moment(1516102320000).year() +"-"+ moment(1516102320000).month()+"-"+moment(1516102320000).day()`

Comment: let me try this

Comment: You will have to format it yourself as I mentioned. `month()` returns 0 for January and 11 for December. Try the exact same code mentioned in the answer. Let me know if it works for you :)